# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Graphic Design's [second moderator election](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Vincent]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5127521121075200/0).

Answer (score 10):

Congrats we know you will make a great Moderator!

Comment: Congratulations Vincent! :)

Answer (score 7):

I'd congratulate you @Vincent, but I'm not sure if that would be "trolling".

Comment: You're brave to test whether or not he's willing to test out the suspension button...leave me out of this! :)

Comment: Well, it's not *really* a test. If that's what he's been plotting... he's now got the power :)

Comment: You can troll me anytime, Scott.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Ryan, Dom and Muhammad for being worthy opponents! And of course thanks everyone for their votes of confidence. I'll try not to screw up too much :)

Comment: I'm so confused! I voted for Vincent but Randy Jones won! ;) Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulation! I am sure you will be a great moderator.